Error after installing Salesforce CLI
Something is not working after I have installed the Salesforce CLI. When I query sfdx update in PowerShell I get this error:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Program Files\sf\client\node_modules\strip-ansi\node_modules\ansi-regex\index.js from C:\Program Files\sf\client\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\Program Files\sf\client\node_modules\strip-ansi\node_modules\ansi-regex\index.js in C:\Program Files\sf\client\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\sf\client\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js:2:19) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Node.js v20.15.0

I understand it is saying something is not supported and I need to do something different, but not sure where to go or what I need to do.  Any advice would be appreciated!
EDIT: After seeing this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081410/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported/69089164#69089164
Do I go here: C:\Program Files\sf\client\node_modules\node-fetch
Open the "Package" file and then add the code snippet
 { 
   "type": "module",
 }

?

This is still not working, can someone help here?

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review

The error you are encountering indicates that there is a compatibility issue between the Salesforce CLI and Node.js regarding the use of ES modules (ECMAScript modules). This is likely due to the fact that Node.js has different ways of handling ES modules and CommonJS modules.
followings outline need to be do again, after than might be its work for you.
Uninstall Node.js
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
Install Node.js v18
Uninstall Salesforce CLI
sfdx plugins:uninstall
Reinstall Salesforce CLI
sfdx plugins:install
Let me know you your response.

Piggybacking off of YRS's answer — it worked btw. I had the same issue with SF-CLI v2.54.6. It seems like SF-CLI uses existing Node.js (if it is installed) for some of the dependencies, which causes the issue. I was able to reinstall node.js v20.15 after SF-CLI was installed.
TO REMEDY ERR_REQUIRE_ESM error:

Uninstall Node.js — Best to use the uninstaller based on their version, but quick and dirty would be Admin PowerShell with command 'Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "C:\Program Files\nodejs"'. This will most likely orphan the entry in the registry for Add Remove Programs (ARP)
Uninstall SF-CLI
Install SF-CLI
Install desired version of Node.js

